# How to optimize the DML operations in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to optimize the below query in sql server 2008.
Particulary  select query i need to optimize.(For eg. totoal records in DB=10000, and if consumed_flag='flase' in 9999 row its taking to much time to retrieve the single record)

```
DECLARE @proxyAcctToken nvarchar(50) 
DECLARE @pmtAcctToken varchar(50)
 DECLARE @ErrorCode varchar(50)
DECLARE @returnMessage varchar(1000)
DECLARE @ErrorStep varchar(100)
DECLARE @tokenSeqNo int
DECLARE @count int
SELECT @count=100000

WHILE(@count>0)
   BEGIN
          SELECT @ErrorCode = @@ERROR
          BEGIN TRY
                 SELECT top 1 @tokenSeqNo=S_NO,@pmtAcctToken = PMT_ACCT_TOKEN, @proxyAcctToken=PROXY_PMT_TOKEN
                 FROM PCTransDB.dbo.MIG_TOKEN_DUMP WHERE CONSUMED_FLAG = 'false'

                 UPDATE PCTransDB.dbo.MIG_TOKEN_DUMP SET CONSUMED_FLAG = 'TRUE', CONSUMED_BY = 'MIGBATCH' WHERE S_NO = @tokenSeqNo
                 PRINT @count


          SELECT  @ErrorCode  = 0

          /*************************************
          *  Return from the Stored Procedure
          *************************************/
   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH   
   PRINT 'IN CATCH BLOCK'
   END CATCH
   SELECT @count = @count-1
   SELECT @proxyAcctToken = null
   SELECT @pmtAcctToken =null
 END
```

Note: Table Details

```
  Column Nmae         DataType  IsNullable
  S_NO                  int      NO
  PROXY_PMT_TOKEN   nvarchar     NO
  PMT_ACCT_TOKEN    nvarchar     NO
  CONSUMED_FLAG        bit       NO
  CONSUMED_BY       nvarchar    YES
```

Comment: Get rid of the `WHILE` loop .... write this `UPDATE` in a single T-SQL statement - that'll speed things up significantly !

Comment: @marc_s.  Particulary select query i need to optimize.(For eg. total records in DB=10000, and if consumed_flag='flase' in 9999 row its taking to much time to retrieve the single record)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you're basically selecting a the `TOP 1` row from your table where `CONSUMED_FLAG = 'false'`, and then you update this row to have `CONSUMED_FLAG = 'true'` and `CONSUMED_BY = 'MIGBATCH'` - and you do this 10'000 times - right?

(*btw side-note: doing a `TOP 1` without having an `ORDER BY` is pretty pointless - which `TOP 1` are you getting? You're not defining an order - so what order do you expect the `TOP 1` to give you the "top-most" row??*)

So why don't you just do:

```
-- use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to select the TOP 10000 rows
-- you need to SPECIFY AN ORDER BY for this to make sense!
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10000 
        S_NO
    FROM    
        PCTransDB.dbo.MIG_TOKEN_DUMP 
    WHERE
        CONSUMED_FLAG = 'false' 
    ORDER BY 
         ??????
)
UPDATE 
    PCTransDB.dbo.MIG_TOKEN_DUMP 
SET 
    CONSUMED_FLAG = 'TRUE', CONSUMED_BY = 'MIGBATCH' 
FROM 
    CTE 
WHERE 
    CTE.S_NO = PCTransDB.dbo.MIG_TOKEN_DUMP.S_NO
```

Basically, just define what you want to update (which rows) by selecting them inside the CTE, and then run **one single `UPDATE` statement** to update all those rows selected. Done. No messy loops, nothing - works like a charm!